# Reusing local objects in multithreaded environment

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following scenario:

- multithreaded application
- I am *not* in control of thread creation. This is managed by the framework (in this case celery)
- I have some objects which are expensive to instantiate, and *not* thread safe. Making them thread safe is not an option.
- The objects can be instantiated in multiple places, but if I am reinstantiating the same object in one thread where it has already been defined, the object should be reused.

I have come up with the following pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import time

class MyObj1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

local = threading.local()
def get_local_obj(key, create_obj, *pars, **kwargs):
    d = local.__dict__
    if key in d: obj = d[key]
    else       :
        obj = create_obj(*pars, **kwargs)
        d[key] = obj
    return obj

class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        myobj1 = get_local_obj('obj1', MyObj1, (self.name))
        for _ in xrange(3):
            print myobj1.name
            time.sleep(1)

def test():
    ths = [Worker() for _ in xrange(2)]
    for t in ths : t.start()

test()
```

Here I am myself creating the threads, since this is just a test, but as said, in the real application I am not in control of the threads.

What I am interested in is in the function `get_local_obj`. I have several questions:

1. Will this logic guarantee that the objects are not shared between threads?
2. Will this logic guarantee that the objects are not instantiated more than once in a thread?
3. Will this memory leak?
4. Do you have any general comments about this approach? Any better suggestion for the scenario suggested above?

### EDIT

Just to clarify: my application is multithraded, but it is not me who is creating the threads. I am simply creating some objects, which happen to run inside threads created by the framework. Some of my objects are not thread safe, so I need to create them only once per thread. Hence `get_my_object`.

### EDIT

local = threading.local() must be defined on the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
class Worker (Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Worker,self).__init__()
    self.m_local = threading.local()

  def get_my_obj(self):
    try:
      obj = self.m_local.my_object
    except AttributeError:
      self.m_local.my_object = create_object()
      obj = self.m_local.my_object
    return obj

  def run(self):
    my_obj = self.get_my_obj()
    # ...
```

In the end it is similar to your example, just cleaner. You keep all the thread - specific code in one place, `run` function "does not know" anything about the initialization, it gets `my_obj` using the getter, ant the getter creates the object only once. [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) will guarantee you that the data is thread specific - that's its job.

I don't see any reason for memory leak there. In the end, you need to sweat a bit to get the leak in python :)

Comment: Thanks, but that won't do. I am not really creating threads in the application (WorkerThread is not mine). The framework is. And I need a *generic* way of creating thread local objects. Please see my edit.

Comment: But your approach to creating the object is interesting. Why do you go the `try / except` route instead of the `__dict__` route that I chose? Any specfic advantage?

Comment: I just don't like idea of accessing fields that are mend to be private

Comment: I see your point. But since I am using a variable key, and not a fixed attribute, I can not use the `try / except` approach. Doing `obj = local[key]` and `local[key] = obj` raises a `TypeError: 'thread._local' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: `x = threading.local()`, after that `print x.hello` raises `Attribute error`, but `x.hello = 100; print x.hello`  prints the value, this is how you use it.

Comment: sure, but my attribute has no fixed value. It is variable. I mean, can I do `x.key = 100` when key is a variable? I think I have to use setattr for that.

Comment: You can always `x=threading.local(); x.my_container = dict()` and the do whatever you want with this dictionary

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, here's a modified version of your code, streamlined somewhat based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408178/355230) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1905593/355230) to related questions. It's still basically the same pattern though.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import time
threadlocal = threading.local()

class MyObj1(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'in MyObj1.__init__(), name =', name
        self.name = name

def get_local_obj(varname, factory, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return getattr(threadlocal, varname)
    except AttributeError:
        obj = factory(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(threadlocal, varname, obj)
        return obj

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        myobj1 = get_local_obj('obj1', MyObj1, self.name)
        for _ in xrange(3):
            print myobj1.name
            time.sleep(1)

def test():
    ths = [Worker() for _ in xrange(3)]
    for t in ths:
        t.start()

test()
```

Actually it's possible to do exactly same thing without a `get_local_obj()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import time
threadlocal = threading.local()

class MyObj1(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'in MyObj1.__init__(), name =', name
        self.name = name

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        threadlocal.myobj1 = MyObj1(self.name)
        for _ in xrange(3):
            print threadlocal.myobj1.name
            time.sleep(1)

def test():
    ths = [Worker() for _ in xrange(3)]
    for t in ths:
        t.start()

test()
```

Comment: I like the `setattr / getattr`. It is cleaner than using `__dict__` and it allows for variable attribute names, which is what I need. The problem with your code, (and my code and Jakub M's code), is that it does not work, as I found the hard way. We need to instantiate only once `threadLocal = threading.local()`, on the global scope, on the main thread. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240093/647991. I will modify my question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, the attribute getting/setting way seems a little more succinct. I wondered about the scoping of the `theading.local()`, fortunately that's easy to fix, thanks for pointing out the problem. I have another idea that I'm trying to figure out how to implement...and will post another answer if it pans out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a another different answer that utilizes an idea I had of having thread-level singletons. It gets completely rid of your `get_local_obj()` function. I haven't done a lot of testing, but so far it seems to work. It may be more than you want because it literally implements what you said you wanted in your last bullet-point:

- The objects can be instantiated in multiple places, but if I am reinstantiating the same object in one thread where it has already been defined, the object should be reused.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import time
threadlocal = threading.local()

class ThreadSingleton(type):
    # called when instances of client classes are created
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instances = threadlocal.__dict__.setdefault(cls.__name__+'.instances', {})
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls] = super(ThreadSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instances[cls]

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ThreadSingleton
    def __init__(self, name):
        print 'in MyClass.__init__(), name =', name
        self.name = name

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        myobj1 = MyClass(self.name)
        for _ in xrange(3):
            print 'myobj1.name:', myobj1.name
            myobj2 = MyClass(self.name+'#2') # this returns myobj1
            print 'myobj2.name:', myobj2.name # so this prints myobj1.name
            time.sleep(1)

def test():
    ths = [Worker() for _ in xrange(3)]
    for t in ths:
        t.start()

test()
```

Note that the output will be somewhat jumbled as it is generated by the different threads. This can be fixed, but I decided not to complicate the essence of this answer by adding it.